# I lost my jury summons, what can I do?

Tags: new-york-state, jury

I recieved a jury summons a little while ago. This summons contained information on where to go as well as some paperwork to bring in. The summons was accidentally thrown out by the cleaning service.

What should I do now?

Comment: Do you remember whether it was for the federal or state court system?

Comment: @phoog it was state

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For the New York State Unified Court System, you can consult their Frequently Asked Questions at http://www.nyjuror.gov/juryQandA.shtml#Q6.

> ## What if my summons or questionnaire is lost?
>
> Contact your local Commissioner of Jurors. Find contact information by scrolling down at “Select County” in the box on the left menu.

When you select your county and click submit, an e-mail message opens addressed to your local Commissioner of Jurors (for example, in Brooklyn, the address is kingscountyjury@nycourts.gov).

Send a message explaining what happened, and they will tell you what to do.